# Why is the bound from -1 to ln(y) and not -ln(y) to ln(y)?

Tags: probability

For the questions before it, it was as simple as just finding what is equal to and then negating it similarly to the bounds given in the PDF. I'm not sure why the bounds for integral for (c) is from -1 to ln(y) and not from -ln(y) to ln(y).

[image: q1]

[image: a1]

update: why isnt it like part (a) where we're finding Y= |X| where it's just from -y to y 
[image: s1]
[image: s2]

Comment: For the question to be answered, you'd have to explain why you think the lower limit should be $-\ln y$. It's hard to explain why something wrong isn't the case without any indication why it might have been the case. Since you're not showing us any of the previous questions you refer to, it's hard to say what disanalogy you might be drawing from them.

Comment: Oh okay! I updated the question to include the parts I'm referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference to part (a) is that in that case expressing the one inequality $|X|\le y$ for $y$ in terms of $X$ yields two inequalities, $-y\le X\le y$, so $X$ is bounded on both sides through $y$ and both limits of the integral are determined by $y$. By contrast, in part (c), the one inequality $\mathrm e^X\le y$ for $y$ results in a single inequality for $X$, namely $X\le\ln y$, so $y$ only determines an upper limit for $X$ and the lower limit needs to be taken from the overall lower limit for $X$, which is $-1$.

Comment: OHHHH I see! I was incorrectly assuming some stuff, thank you so much for clearing it up!

Answer (score 6):

The reason as to why the bounds are from $-1$ to $\ln(y)$ comes from the support of the distribution of $X$.

We see that

$$P(Y \leq y) = P(e^X \leq y) = P(X \leq \ln(y)).$$

We know that $\ln(y)$ is the upper bound for the integral given the logic presented in the probability. Given the fact that the random variable $X$ has support from $-1$ to $1$ exclusively, we know that
$$P(X \leq \ln(y)) = P(-\infty < X \leq \ln(y)) = P(-1 < X \leq \ln(y)),$$

since any realization of $X$ lower than or equal to $-1$ has probability of $0$ occurring. Thus, the lower bound on the integral for calculation $P(X \leq \ln(y))$ is $-1$ rather than $-\ln(y)$.